# Unexpected token '<' jest and testing-library/react-native with typescript test file

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when running the following test file:

```js
// TestComp.test.tsx
import React from "react";
import { TextInput, View } from "react-native";

import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react-native";

const TestComp = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput testID="test-input" onChangeText={(txt) => console.log(txt)}></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};

describe("Testcomp", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("test me", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<TestComp />);
    const testInput = getByTestId("test-input");
    fireEvent.changeText(testInput, "hello");
  });
});
```

Error when running `yarn jest`:

```
    Details:

    /mnt/ubuntu/home/richardwu/code/topspin/src/components/TestComp.test.tsx:46
        return (<react_native_1.View>
                ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      at compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
```

The error disappears if I change the file to `jsx`. The issue is the components I will be importing will be in `tsx` files, so ideally I want `jest` to be able to run with `tsx` files.

I've followed the instructions for setting up typescript with jest, where I have the following config files:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: "react-native",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/?!(react-icons)"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"],
};
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  };
};
```

```
// package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.5",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^5.1.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-auth-session": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-swipe-cards": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.34",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: With your current setup, `jest` will use the config from your `package.json`. To have it point to your `jest.config.js` file you can update the `test` script to `jest --config <insert_path_to_jest.config.js>`.

Comment: I just tried running it with the `--config` flag: doesn't seem like it fixes the issue though.

Comment: try adding `ts-loader` or `awesome-ts-loader`

Comment: Have you tried using `babel-jest` for both JSX and TSX files?  It looks like you have `@babel/preset-typescript` installed so that should work.

Comment: I think this should help you 
source: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html

`import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
  <Link page="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</Link>
);`

Comment: @MarkSkelton Modfiying the `tsx?` transform in my jest.config.js to `babel-jest` worked! Feel free to write up the answer and I'll mark it resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using Babel and `@babel/preset-typescript`, you can update your Jest config to use `babel-jest` for both JavaScript and TypeScript files. Simply update your `transform` regex to the following.

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: "react-native",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/?!(react-icons)"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"],
};
```

With that change, you can then uninstall `ts-jest` from your project since it will no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case was installing ts-jest with `npm i -D ts-jest` and configuring like this:

```
// jest.config.js
const {defaults: tsjPreset} = require('ts-jest/presets');
module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: 'react-native',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
      },
    ],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons|react-native-config|@react-native-async-storage)/)',
  ],
}


// tsconfig.spec.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```